# CSS positioning text node in block element (table)

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm looking for a solution to but a text node in the vertical top of a block element.
I'm using a td with rowspan and this makes the text inside of the td centering in the vertical center.

Thats what it looks like

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">to but in vertical top</td>
    <td>s0me</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>t3xt</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

For some reasons I do not want to use a

```
<td>nbsp;</td>
```

in the second row.

//EDIT:

-.- 1 more minute in google gave me this:

```
<td rowspan="2" style="vertical-align:text-top;">text</td>
```

which works perfectly. sry for unnecessary post

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're asking. Perhaps explain some more or create a JSFiddle?

Comment: you can put align="top" as an attribute of the td ``<td rowspan="2" align="top">``. if you dont want to do that you can use the css [vertical-align](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp) property

Comment: You know, if you really want to delete this, there's nothing stopping you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/vertical-align) property on table cells.

See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/TgLUK/

It's as simple as selecting your table with CSS selector (or applying a style tag), that defines:

```
vertical-align: top;
```

Like:

```
td.topped
{
    vertical-align: top;
}
```